# ObservableField not propagating changes

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying the databinding feature for Android and it seems that the Observable fields do not propagate the change to the UI.

If I extend the `BaseObservable` class everything works as intended, however when I switch to `ObservableBoolean` or `ObservableField` the data changes but it's not being propagated to the UI.

the model

```
public class User {
  public final ObservableBoolean tapped = new ObservableBoolean(false);

    public boolean isTapped() {
        return tapped.get();
    }

    public void setTapped(boolean tapped) {
        this.tapped.set(tapped);
    }
}
```

the layout

```
<layout 
    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="User"/>
          ....
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@{user.tapped ? @color/colorAccent : @color/white}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> user_holder.onClickTest(user)}">

        ......
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've confused the poor data binding system. Not only do you have a public field, but you also have getters and setters for it. Android Data Binding first attempts to bind to the getter and if that fails, binds to the  field.

If you change the name of the the name used in the methods (e.g. `isPersonTapped()`, `setPersonTapped(...)`) then you won't have a problem. Since you have the accessor methods, you could also use a private field and notify the change yourself:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
    private boolean tapped = false;

    @Bindable
    public boolean isTapped() {
        return tapped;
    }

    public void setTapped(boolean tapped) {
        this.tapped = tapped;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.tapped);
    }
}
```

Comment: It was the getters and setters, I removed them, works fine now, thanks!